# Firebase data structure/indexes for folder system

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have the following data structure:

```
"users": {
    $userid: {
        "forms": {
            "ID_OF_FORM 1": { "name": "Name goes here" },
            "ID_OF_FORM 2": { "name": "Name goes here" }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to put my "forms" in a folder system to better organize all of them for the user. Right now I call them using `/users/auth.id/forms/ID`. I was planning on putting objects inside the `forms` object but I don't think i'll be able to call them with just the  **form id** anymore if I do that.

I can't wrap my head around how I should store these folders so that they can easily be displayed.

- I need to display all the folders inside **root** or the active id of
  a folder that a user is currently in.
- I also need to be able to call a form using the id of the form

Do you think this would work? Does anyone have any better suggestions on going about doing this?

```
"users": {
    $userid: {
        "forms": {
            "ID_OF_FORM 1": { "name": "Name goes here", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER" },
            "ID_OF_FORM 2": { "name": "Name goes here", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER" }
        },
        "folders": {
            "ID_OF_FOLDER 1": { "name": "name of folder" },
            "ID_OF_FOLDER 2": { "name": "name of folder" },
            "ID_OF_FOLDER 3": { 
                "name": "name of folder",
                "ID_OF_FOLDER 4": { "name": "would this even work" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me, although it is difficult to be certain unless one knows all use-cases (for which StackOverflow is not really the right forum).

I would change the `folders` a bit into:

```
    "folders": {
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 1": { "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 2": { "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 3": { "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 4": { "name": "would this even work", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER 3" }
    }
```

Otherwise you run the risk of going over the 32 level limit that Firebase imposes on the depth of the tree. The nice thing is that you can directly access any folder by its ID here.

You *may* consider using a single top-level node for all item types, both forms and folders (and anything else that might come along as you're building the application):

```
    "items": {
        "ID_OF_FORM 1": { "type": "form", "name": "Name goes here", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER" },
        "ID_OF_FORM 2": { "type": "form", "name": "Name goes here", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER" }
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 1": { "type": "folder", "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 2": { "type": "folder", "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 3": { "type": "folder", "name": "name of folder" },
        "ID_OF_FOLDER 4": { "type": "folder", "name": "would this even work", "folder_id": "ID_OF_FOLDER 3" }
    }
```

But I don't think this is too beneficial for your use-case at the moment. Given what you've said, the split between folders and forms seem pretty good.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Right now I have folders and forms separate for good reason (there are more attributes to the form that I didn't list) But i'm always open to suggestions and the pro's and con's of doing it other ways. As always, I appreciate your help.